# Most Active Contributors Quarterly Report - 2nd Quarter 2018

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the third Quarterly edition of the Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

While similar to the monthly report, this report differs in that it contains fewer sections but lists the top 10 users (instead of 5) in each of those sections.

This report will be published after each calendar year quarter. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for 2nd Quarter 2018

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Quarterly Reputation Leader Board
3. Quarterly Most Active Editors Award
4. Quarterly Most Active Voters Award
5. Quarterly Most Close Votes Reviewed Award
6. Quarterly Most First Posts Reviewed Award
7. Quarterly Most Late Answers Reviewed Award
8. Quarterly Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award
9. Quarterly Most Reopen Reviews Award
10. Quarterly Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Ranked 1st Summary List
12. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                    SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                1,180
2   Allan                    1,040
3   Nimesh Neema               630
4   grg                        560
5   bmike                      340
6   fsb                        240
7   Tetsujin                   220
8   PeterJ                     150
9   dwightk, Mark              140
10  nohillside, Glorfindel,
    Scot, Jbis, Swisher Sweet  130
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 2,550.

---

[image: TITLE: QUARTERLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]

A total of 2,779 users earned reputation during the quarter. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/quarter/apple/2018-04-01).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema             375
2   bmike                    183
3   Monomeeth                180
4   grg                      170
5   Allan                    128
6   Pang                     124
7   IconDaemon               117
8   nohillside                94
9   klanomath                 66
10  Matt                      58
```

A big thank you to all 29 users who edited questions or answers this quarter!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  4,383
2   Monomeeth               2,149
3   Nimesh Neema            1,039
4   bmike                     488
5   grg                       466
6   Melvin Jefferson          331
7   Citizen                   283
8   creidhne                  251
9   nohillside                182
10  user97627                 178
```

A big thank you to all 187 users who voted on questions or answers this quarter!<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1. Note: Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST CLOSE VOTES REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    166
2   Mark                     143
3   Monomeeth                119
4   dwightk                   94
5   Nimesh Neema              77
6   fsb                       70
7   nohillside                65
8   IconDaemon                54
9   Scot                      49
10  grg                       45
```

A big thank you to all 42 users who reviewed Close Votes this quarter!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST FIRST POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                844
2   Nimesh Neema             521
3   Allan                    276
4   fsb                      263
5   nohillside               197
6   grg                      184
7   Jbis                     172
8   Scot                     171
9   IconDaemon               116
10  Melvin Jefferson          94
```

A big thank you to all 65 users who reviewed First Posts this quarter!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LATE ANSWERS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    299
2   Monomeeth                189
3   Glorfindel               117
4   Nimesh Neema              94
5   Scot                      64
6   grg                       60
7   fsb                       56
8   IconDaemon                37
9   Tetsujin                  33
10  Jules                     31
```

A big thank you to all 45 users who reviewed Late Answers this quarter!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LOW-QUALITY POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    185
2   Monomeeth                 55
3   fsb                       51
4   Nimesh Neema              45
5   Scot                      40
6   IconDaemon                35
7   Tetsujin                  28
9   grg                       25
10  nohillside, fd0           20
```

A big thank you to all 30 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this quarter!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST REOPEN POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    55
2   Monomeeth                24
3   fsb                      22
4   Tetsujin                 18   
5   Mark                     16
6   grg                      15
7   dwightk                  14
8   nohillside               13
9   Glorfindel               11
10  Mark                      9
```

A big thank you to all 21 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this quarter!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST SUGGESTED EDITS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth               233
2   Allan                   216
3   Nimesh Neema            128
4   grg                      89
5   Glorfindel               67
6   nohillside               64
7   Scot                     56
8   bmike, fd0               47
9   fsb                      40
10  dwightk                  39
```

A big thank you to all 88 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this quarter!

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [grg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Close Votes Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**6.    Most First Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**7.    Most Late Answers Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**8.    Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**9.    Most Reopen Reviews Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In the 2nd Quarter of 2018 our [Moderators](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned 1,529 flags with an average handling time of 23 minutes. In summary, we:

- deleted 825 comments
- deleted 773 posts
- closed 486 posts
- edited 698 posts
- created 424 posts
- created 1,390 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)